# WooCommerce: Hide products with the word "master" in product Title

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to hide products in WooCommerce, based on their title when the word "master" is in product title.

Do you know how I do that?

EDIT:
The word „master“ is not in title, master is in SKU = (991-64002-18x12-00000-master). Is there anyone, who can know, how I can do that? Thanks

Comment: How do you access each of the products in WooCommerce? Is it a list? If so, you can iterate over your list, then you can check `if 'master' in str(product).lower()`. Do you have an example to start with?

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we expect you to provide in your question your real code attempt. I answer your question exceptionally.

To hide all products that have the word "master" in their SKU:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_product_query' );
function custom_product_query( $q ){
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        global $wpdb;
        
        $to_find  = 'master';
        $hide_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' && meta_value LIKE '%$to_find%'");
        
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $hide_ids );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I want looking for „word“ in SKU, what change in function?

Comment: SKU with word „master“ look like 991-64002-18x12-00000-master